# How to connent to Oracle database with SSH in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, oracle, intellij-idea, ssh

I'm trying to configure the data source using SSH to access the Database from IntelliJ off-campus. The configuration is as shown in the screenshots, and I got

> [08006][17002] IO Error: Got minus one from a read call, connect lapse 30003 ms., Authentication lapse 0 ms. oracle.net.ns.NetException: Got minus one from a read call.

In fact, I've succeeded to connect to the DB with the `loginProxy()` and `loginDB()` in a Java program. From running the code, I knew that the jdbcPort should be dynamic, and I assume that's also what should be filled in the "Port" blank in the "General" tab in "Data Source and Drivers" configuration window.

---

**So here comes the problem, how can I configure it if the Port to be filled in is DYNAMIC? Or did I get anything wrong so that actually there should be another approach?**

An additional question: `String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + jdbcHost + ":" + jdbcPort + "/" + database;` What URL format is used here? It doesn't look like SID, Service Name, or TNS, but it does work... and it's funny that when I substitute the "/" with ":", which matches the SID format, it doesn't work anymore...

```
    /**
     * Login the proxy. Do not change this function.
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean loginProxy() {
        if (getYESorNO("Using ssh tunnel or not?")) { // if using ssh tunnel
            String[] namePwd = getUsernamePassword("Login cs lab computer");
            String sshUser = namePwd[0];
            String sshPwd = namePwd[1];
            try {
                proxySession = new JSch().getSession(sshUser, proxyHost, proxyPort);
                proxySession.setPassword(sshPwd);
                Properties config = new Properties();
                config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                proxySession.setConfig(config);
                proxySession.connect();
                proxySession.setPortForwardingL(forwardHost, 0, databaseHost, databasePort);
                forwardPort = Integer.parseInt(proxySession.getPortForwardingL()[0].split(":")[0]);
                //  forwardPort is set here, seems to be dynamic...
            } catch (JSchException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
            jdbcHost = forwardHost;  //  this is used in case of SSH connection, which is "localhost"
            jdbcPort = forwardPort;  //  this is used in case of SSH connection
        } else {
            jdbcHost = databaseHost;
            jdbcPort = databasePort;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

```
    /**
     * Login the oracle system. Change this function under instruction.
     * 
     * @return boolean
     */
    public boolean loginDB() {
        String username = "myDBUsername";
        String password = "myDBPassword";

        /* Do not change the code below */

        String URL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + jdbcHost + ":" + jdbcPort + "/" + database;

        try {
            System.out.println("Logging " + URL + " ...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, username, password);
            return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image: SSH/SSL - Data Source and Drivers - IntelliJ IDEA]

Answer (score 1):

On general tab you need to specify real db server hostname and port, not localhost. With configured SSH tunnel on next tab all the things for connection will be done automatically.